# Why number is not a valid NCName

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I have this xml to validate:

```
 <row Id="411" TagName="python" Count="9" ExcerptPostId="7058" WikiPostId="7057"/>
  <row Id="413" TagName="faces" Count="3" ExcerptPostId="5232" WikiPostId="5231"/>
  <row Id="414" TagName="global" Count="8" ExcerptPostId="5270" WikiPostId="5269"/>
  <row Id="415" TagName="wikimedia-commons" Count="5" ExcerptPostId="5301" WikiPostId="5300"/>
  <row Id="416" TagName="photographs" Count="7"/>
```

But if i define id as xs:ID it gives me error 411 is not a valid NCNAME...Seems that ID cant be an integer and dont know why, in theory is a well formed string.

```
<xs:complexType name="typeRow">
  <xs:attribute name="Id" type="xs:ID" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="TagName" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
      <xs:attribute name="Count" type="xs:positiveInteger" use="required"/>
      <xs:attribute name="ExcerptPostId" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
      <xs:attribute name="WikiPostId" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

How can i write that Id in xml is an ID ( unique and obviously cant be repeated )

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

According to xsd types definition:
The type **xsd:ID** is used for an attribute that uniquely identifies an element in an XML document. An xsd:ID value must be an NCName. This means that it must start with a letter or underscore, and can only contain letters, digits, underscores, hyphens, and periods.

Comment: Ooh i thought that an xml name would be valid, any string... how can i restrict an unique element ? Thanks

Comment: It depends on which identifiers you are going to use. If they are xsd:ID type, then your row Id should be like "isbn-0836217462"

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `xs:ID`, define an `xs:unique` constraint in your schema. If the rows are children of a `rows` element, you want

```
<xs:element name="rows">
  <xs:complexType>....</xs:complexType>
  <xs:unique name="rowID">
    <xs:selector xpath="row"/>
    <xs:field xpath="@Id"/>
  </xs:unique>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: No as i defined above i have a rowType, which one attribute is ID ( in the xml file), so i have  to avoid duplicated id in xsd.. dont know how to do it..unique should be part of typeID that would be the data instead of xs:ID that is not allowed... thanks

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand what you are trying to say in your comment.

Comment: Sorry my bad english, i only need a: <xs:attribute name="Id" type="typeID" use="required"/> and i need to define one typeID that would be positiveInteger and not repeated in the xml file ( unique value)... Hope you can understand now....

Comment: `xs:ID` is anomalous because it defines both a value set (the same value set as `xs:NCName`) and a uniqueness constraint. It's basically replicating what you can do with ID attributes in a DTD, for compatibility. It's not suitable for your needs because you want to use values that aren't allowed by `xs:ID`. So you need the more general capability for defining uniqueness constraints, which is `xs:unique`.